# magento 1.7 Left customer account navigation is missing

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am running Magento 1.7 and I added sidebar navigation ( by codnitive ) extension, Unfortunately  Left customer account navigation is missing and I can't get it back

Can I use sidebar navigation ( by codnitive ) extension in the left 
 categories navigation and not in Left customer account navigation

Please help me

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem mentioned above, On codnitive/sidenav.xml search Customer account and locate `<reference name="left">` and added the below code

```
 <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">

                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>My Account</label></action>

                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Edit Account Information</label></action>

                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>

            </block>
```

now it's working correctly.